# Get native JavaVM and JNIEnv handles in Xamarin c# project

Tags: c#, android, android-ndk, xamarin.android

I have an android native library that I would like to use via P/Invoke in a Xamarin c# project.

Initialization call for the library expects the following parameters:

```
JavaVM * javaVM
JNIEnv * jniEnv
void *   activityObject
```

On the sample ndk project from the library, initialisation is set as (directly at the beginning of android_main entry point):

```
javaVM = app->activity->vm;
activityObject = app->activity->clazz;
```

jniEnv is set as:

```
javaVM->AttachCurrentThread( javaVM, &jniEnv, NULL );
```

And then the Initialize dll function is called with those parameters.

Now I would like to initialize those pointers from a c# Xamarin project.

app->activity does point to the following [ANativeActivity](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/struct_a_native_activity.html#a5e163c28566d4563eafeabd7dcab7eeb) which I need equivalent handles to initialize in my c# activity.

So considering and Activity object "act", I need to perform the following:

```
public unsafe class MainActivity : Activity
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ndklib.so")]
    public static int InitLibrary(IntPtr javaVM, IntPtr jniEnv, IntPtr activityObject);

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
         IntPtr javaVM = ???
         IntPtr jniEnv = ???
         IntPtr activityObject = ????

         InitLibrary(javaVM, jniEnv, activityObject);
    }

}
```

1/ I would expect to get activity Object as:

```
IntPtr activityObject = act.Class.Handle;
```

2/I can't find how to retrieve a JavaVM * handle anywhere.

The only close thing I can find is in JNIEnv :

```
 static IntPtr java_vm;
```

Which is a private field not accessible anywhere (I can access it via reflection only), is that correct? (and if so, is there's a way to get that handle without resorting to reflection tricks?).

3/ Once I get this JavaVM handle, I still can't see any equivalent to call AttachCurrentThread within c# Xamarin api.

Is it possible to just perform the following, and get the current handle (which would imply this is already attached) ? or is there another way to do so?

```
IntPtr jniEnv = JNIEnv.Handle;
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to start activity with java from mono android?

Comment: Activity is Mono (standard activity c# class), and code I need to call is native (dllexport, P/Invoke), but requires those 3 arguments on it's initialize function).

Comment: Updated question, with some activity, hope that makes what I need a bit clearer

Comment: Is this [Java Native Invoke Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/JNIDemo/) what you need? I didn't see how to pass arguments through.

Comment: No, I need (from updated answer with link to ANativeActivity), the equivalent calls to retrieve the vm field eg : The global handle on the process's Java VM) from inside my c# activity. Same for the activity handle (clazz field in case of native version). Then I can pass those to the unmanaged library, which requires those.

Comment: @catflier , have you found a way to get java vm ptr? I have similar problem.

Comment: @Crossman, did you find an answer?

Comment: I did not so far, the only valid one is to do a getfield with reflection to access java_vm (in JNIEnv , static member)

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an older post, but I've been on the hunt for this as well. Looks like we now have this in .NET Maui:

```
Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.References.GetJavaVM(out nint invocationPointer);
```

I'm going to give this a try in my app to see if it works. It may take some time to pull it all together, but I wanted to share progress in case it helps to unstick anyone else who's stuck on this.